# The final clause of this sentence throws the sound of this sentence off to me, but what are the grammatical reasons?

Tags: grammar

Here is the sentence that was constructed as a part of a vision statement. I KNOW in my bones it is off, but can't say why.  I would love some insight!

> Our goal is to establish the best sector as the major sector of the industry, that it deserves to be.

Comment: The whole thing doesn't make any sense.  You simply don't realize that until you get to the end.

Comment: *The best sector as the major sector* is just strange. I can force it to make some kind of sense if I really try, but it shouldn't be phrased that way.

Comment: It would probably make more sense if you replaced the comma with a semicolon or full stop. "That it deserves to be" is a grammatical (but suboptimal) sentence: it's unusual to put the object at the start, and "It deserves to be that" is a more usual way of expressing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea as to why the end may seem off, but as was noted, the sentence as a whole does not make sense. I may be able to make better suggestions for revision with additional context.

Some possibilities:

> Our goal is to establish our sector as the best in the industry, as it deserves to be
>
> Our goal is to ensure that the biggest sector in the industry is also the best sector in the industry
>
> Our goal is to ensure that the best sector in the industry becomes the biggest
>
> Our goal is to establish our sector as the major competitor in our industry that it deserves to be

---

Regarding the ending: the part after the comma is a dependent clause that is modifying an earlier part of your sentence.

Commas are only used with dependent clauses that are non-essential to the meaning of a sentence. Modifiers using "that" are typically essential to a sentence, and thus should not be used with a comma.

Some examples of dependent clauses that *are* essential:

- I want to be the best writer that I can be
- She saw walls that were 10 feet high

In contrast:

- The walls, which were 10 feet high, were rather imposing
- I want to win the writing award, which I know I deserve

Comment: Thanks: I fixed the missing word and added a version that aligns with your suggestion